# What's happening when I use for(i in object) in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

To iterate over the properties of an `Object` in AS3 you can use `for(var i:String in object)` like this:

**Object:**

```
var object:Object = {

    thing: 1,
    stuff: "hats",
    another: new Sprite()

};
```

**Loop:**

```
for(var i:String in object)
{
    trace(i + ": " + object[i]);
}
```

**Result:**

```
stuff: hats
thing: 1
another: [object Sprite]
```

The order in which the properties are selected however seems to vary and never matches anything that I can think of such as alphabetical property name, the order in which they were created, etc. In fact if I try it a few different times in different places, the order is completely different.

Is it possible to access the properties in a given order? What is happening here?

Comment: The way I think of an object as declared above, is like a hash Table as seen in some other languages, where you can never trust the order due to how it internally handles itself. General idea can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: good question.  while i have no idea why iterating over object properties is seemingly random, i recall past threads discussing similar problems and the solution was to create a dictionary that is passed to an array sorted by either the keys or values of the dictionary.  i'd also be interested to know what is happening here.

Comment: I think @ToddBFisher has the right idea here. In C++ this would basically be an "unordered map", specifically std::unordered_map from the new C++11 standard implemented in the TR1 release. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_associative_containers_(C%2B%2B) and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/ for more details on the concept at work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer just to compliment [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083707/562566) with some extra insight by looking directly at the flash player source code. We can actually see the AVM code that specifically provides this functionality and it's written in C++. We can see inside ArrayObject.cpp the following code:

```
// Iterator support - for in, for each
Atom ArrayObject::nextName(int index)
{
    AvmAssert(index > 0);

    int denseLength = (int)getDenseLength();
    if (index <= denseLength)
    {
        AvmCore *core = this->core();
        return core->intToAtom(index-1);
    }
    else
    {
        return ScriptObject::nextName (index - denseLength);
    }
}
```

As you can see when there is a legitimate property (object) to return, it is looked up from the `ScriptObject` class, specifically the `nextName()` method. If we look at those methods within ScriptObject.cpp:

```
Atom ScriptObject::nextName(int index)
{
    AvmAssert(traits()->needsHashtable());
    AvmAssert(index > 0);

    InlineHashtable *ht = getTable();
    if (uint32_t(index)-1 >= ht->getCapacity()/2)
        return nullStringAtom;
    const Atom* atoms = ht->getAtoms();
    Atom m = ht->removeDontEnumMask(atoms[(index-1)<<1]);
    if (AvmCore::isNullOrUndefined(m))
        return nullStringAtom;
    return m;
}
```

We can see that indeed, as people have pointed out here that the VM is using a hash table. However in these functions there is a specific index supplied, which would suggest, at first glance, that there must then be specific ordering.

If you dig deeper (I won't post all the code here) there are a whole slew of methods from different classes involved in the for in/for each functionality and one of them is the method `ScriptObject::nextNameIndex()` which basically pulls up the whole hash table and just starts providing indices to valid objects within the table and increments the original index supplied in the argument, so long as the next value points to a valid object. If I'm right in my interpretation, this would be the cause behind your random lookup and I don't believe there would be any way here to force a standardized/ordered map in these operations.

**Sources**
For those of you who might want to get the source code for the open source portion of the flash player, you can grab it from the following mercurial repositories (you can download a snapshop in zip like github so you don't have to install mercurial):

http://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-central - This is the "stable" or "release" repository

http://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-redux - This is the development branch. The most recent changes to the AVM will be found here. This includes the support for Android and such. Adobe is still updating and open sourcing these parts of the flash player, so it's good current and official stuff.

While I'm at it, this might be of interest as well: http://code.google.com/p/redtamarin/. It's a branched off (and rather mature) version of the AVM and can be used to write server-side actionscript. Neat stuff and has a ton of information that gives insight into the workings of the AVM so I thought I'd include it too.

Comment: No problem. I'm going to edit it and post the sources where people can get the open source portion of the player.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is [documented](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f5b) (emphasis mine):

> The `for..in` loop iterates through the properties of an object, or the elements of an array. For example, you can use a `for..in` loop to iterate through the properties of a generic object **(object properties are not kept in any particular order, so properties may appear in a seemingly random order)**

How the properties are stored and retrieved appears to be an implementation detail, which isn't covered in the documentation. As ToddBFisher mentions in a comment, though, a data structure commonly used to implement associative arrays is the [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). It's even mentioned in [this page about associative arrays in AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eea.html), and if you [inspect the AVM code as shown by Ascension Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10084227/106224), you'll find exactly such an implementation. As described, there is no notion of order or sorting in typical hash tables.

I don't believe there is a way to access the properties in a specific order unless you store that order somehow.