# loop through object properties in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an object that gets properties added in this sequence.

```
Home
School
living
status
sound
Memory
```

When I loop through the object they don't come out in that sequence. How do I get them to come out in this order.

data is the object

```
for (var i:String in data)
{
    trace(i + ": " + data[i]);
}
```

Is there a way to sort it maybe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083064/whats-happening-when-i-use-fori-in-object-in-as3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to sort the order that you can access properties is manually. Here is a function I have created for you to do just that:

```
function getSortedPairs(object:Object):Array
{
    var sorted:Array = [];

    for(var i:String in object)
    {
        sorted.push({ key: i, value: object[i] });
    }

    sorted.sortOn("key");

    return sorted;
}
```

Trial:

```
var test:Object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 };
var sorted:Array = getSortedPairs(test);

for each(var i:Object in sorted)
{
    trace(i.key, i.value);
}
```

Comment: I need to sort both the property key and the value not just the value. how would I go about that

Comment: Right but this will only either sort key or value but I need after the sort to be able to access the key and the value

Comment: I see whats going on but the values and keys are still not coming out the way they were first added to the object.

Comment: Living,
Memory,Home,
School, status,
sound,
title

Comment: @Chapsterj There is no way to do that other than store that order manually i.e. populating a 'sorted' array like I have line by line in the desired order.

Comment: I guess that defeats the purpose of having them dynamic if I have to add them manually.

Comment: @Chapsterj Unfortunately there is nothing you can do. This is just the nature of how properties of objects are stored in memory (see the link I put on your question for more info).

Comment: Would a Dictionary work instead of an object. Or would the dictionary come out the same way

Comment: Why would you flag this as correct if it clearly wasn't your answer. If you want to sort properties I would suggest using an array collection. Collections have a sort function that you can define to sort anyway you want it to sort.

Comment: Well it wasn't exactly the answer but it showed me that I need to change my way of doing it in order to make it work and that gives me my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The link Marty shared explains what is happening pretty well and his answer is excellent too.

Another solution you might also consider if order matters is to use a `Vector`.

```
// Init the vector
var hectorTheVector:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();

// Can add items by index
hectorTheVector[0] = "Home";
hectorTheVector[1] = "School";
hectorTheVector[2] = "living";

// Or add items by push
hectorTheVector.push("status");
hectorTheVector.push("sound");
hectorTheVector.push("Memory");

//See all items in order
for(var i:int = 0; i < hectorTheVector.length; i++){
    trace(hectorTheVector[i]);
}

/* Traces out:
Home
School
living
status
sound
Memory
*/
```

An `Array` would also preserve order. here is a [good topic on sorting Arrays](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html)

Answer (score 0):

**ActionScript 3, you can decode JSON string into Object through this function**

```
function createJSONObjectFromString(data: String):Object {
        var obj: Object = new Object();
        data = data.replace("{", "");
        data = data.replace("}", "");
        var data_array = [];
        if (data != ""){
            if (data.indexOf(",")){
                while (data.indexOf(", ") >= 0){
                    data = data.replace(", ", ",");
                }
                data_array = data.split(",");
            }else{
                data_array = [data];
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++){
            var prop_val = data_array[i].split(":");
            obj[removeSlashes(prop_val[0])] = removeSlashes(prop_val[1]);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```